# Preprocessing columns in R dataset with mixed characters and signs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two columns in a dataset and both of them are factors. I would like to group the results based on those values. But before that, I need to clean the dataset first. I checked solutions of how to remove dollar sign and empty rows as well as commas. But I don't have an idea about how to clean the whole dataset that could meet all those requirements mentioned as below:

raw dataset df

```
        Experience   Salary

 2      5-10 years   $30,000-39,999
 3      5-10 years   100,000-124,999
 4      10-20 years  15,000-19,999
 5      5-10 years   125,000-149,999
 6      3-5 years   
 7      < 1 years    <$999             
 8      20+ years    >200,000
```

The first, I would like to remove empty rows(I managed to do this, it 's ok).
For Experience column, remove years and keep only numbers after hyphen sign e.g. 5-10years convert to 10. Less than one shows as 1.
For salary rows, I want to remove dollar, comma, ">" and "<" signs.  Keep only numbers behind the hyphen part e.g. $30,000-39,999 convert to 39999 and "<$999" changes to 999

The expected output:

```
         Experience   Salary 

  2      10           39999
  3      10          124999
  4      20           19999
  5      10          149999
  6      1              999             
  7      20          200000
```

How should I clean the dataset? Any advise? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some regex for this data cleaning process.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Experience != '' & Salary != '') %>%
  mutate(Experience = as.numeric(sub('.*?(\\d+)\\+?\\s*years', '\\1', Experience)),
         Salary = as.numeric(gsub('.*-|[,<$>]', '', Salary)))

#  Experience Salary
#1         10  39999
#2         10 124999
#3         20  19999
#4         10 149999
#5          1    999
#6         20 200000
```

To extract `Experience` the logic is to extract the last number which is followed by an optional `+`, 0 or more whitespace followed by `'years'`.

To get `Salary` we remove everything until `'-'` and extra symbols like `,<$>`.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak,  yes, that 's problem I had-- the regex approach. Thank a lot!